# How to make a java gui in Jess as an applet?

Tags: java, user-interface, applet, jess

I have an interface written in Jess (one of the java libraries) that has a panel and a combo box

I wanna make it run as applet. so I can embed it on the web!

Here is my applet.java,

```
package uges.applets;

import java.applet.Applet;
import jess.*;
Applet applet = new Applet();
public class JessApplet extends Applet
{
public void init()
{
Rete engine = new Rete(applet);
try
{
    engine.batch("ug-pro.clp");
    engine.reset();

} catch (JessException e)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

The error was cannot open file ug-pro.clp .. should I put it in a specific folder? and Can I make my GUI in jess as an applet ?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I make my GUI in jess as an applet?

From the [info. page on Jess](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jess/info).

> Jess can be used to build Java servlets, EJBs, **applets**, and full applications that use knowledge in the form of declarative rules to draw conclusions and make inferences.

```
Rete engine = new Rete();
```

Note particularly the constructor [new Rete(Applet)](http://www.jessrules.com/jess/docs/71/api/jess/Rete.html#Rete%28java.applet.Applet%29).

Comment: +1 Good answer, Andrew. That constructor indeed enables the Rete object to find scripts on the server.

Comment: @Ernest I did not look deeply into the docs., but that jumped out at me (and barked).  You have experience with the API, or looked further?

Comment: @Ernest LOL, I should have looked further. :P BTW - was thinking as I looked at the Jess info. page, that it could do with a direct link to the Jess site(1) (as well as perhaps the docs., and a couple of other of the more interesting bits).  I'm guessing you can make that happen?  1) To get there, I needed to type the URL that appeared in the tool-tip for the [tag:jess] tag.  The URL appears nowhere (I can see) in the info. page itself.

Comment: @Ernest @Andrew I have changed the code as above .. Now when I run the applet, two windows open: the applet viewr and the jess GUI .. I have put the ug-pro.clp in the bin folder ,, so it can be opened by the applet .. Butthe problem now is when I embed the JessApplet applet in an HTML in the following code:  `<applet code="JessApplet.class"></applet>` .. I got an exception that reports `class not found exception caused by java.io.file not found exception` .. I really need it to run on the web .. I've searched a lot but the resources to solve my problem are few! Any ideas please?!

Comment: I put the html file in the same folder of JessApplet.class and it didn't work! Both of them are in the bin folder of the java project ...

Comment: This sounds like a "You must learn to walk before you can run" problem. First figure out how to run a "Hello, World" applet in your environment (sounds like maybe you're using Eclipse?) Then try to run a "Hello, Jess" applet that uses Jess but doesn't load a script. Finally, modify the applet to load a script.